# 入力された文章に対し紐付けた文章を返すアプリの作成

Tags: javascript, php, html, データベース設計, 検索

データベースに入力した文字に該当したユーザーの文章に対して紐付けた文章を返すアプリの作成について詳しい方に伺いたいのですが、ユーザーに入力してもらった文字列からあらかじめデータベースに設定した文字と該当したものがあればユーザーに回答を返すアプリを作りたく試行錯誤しております。

例えばユーザーが「ケーキが好きです。」など自由に文章を入力したら、データベースに「好き」という文字に反応して、ユーザーに「スウィーツが好き」などとこちらが予め作成済みの文章を該当ユーザーに返す仕様のアプリを作りたいのですが、イメージとしては検索や占いアプリの応用になるのかなと思います。

データベースやPHPなどの知識も必要かと思いますが、まだ知識が及ばないので、ライブラリーや参考になるソースコードなどご教示願いますでしょうか。

HTMLはできますが、PHPやJavaScriptはライブラリーを引用する程度の実力しかないので、グーグルのGlideやスプレッドシートを使って作成は可能なものでしょうか。もしくはほかのプラットホームなどオススメがあれば教えて頂けませんでしょうか。

ほかの方に教えて頂いたのですが、主要なロジックは大体次になるのではないかとのことでした。

1. ユーザー入力文字列を形態素解析
2. 1の結果から名詞や動詞の「見出し語」or「基本形の文字列」を抽出
3. 2で抽出した文字列をつかってDBを検索
4. 3の検索結果に対してこちらがDBに該当する検索結果に対してあらかじめ設定した文字列をユーザーに返す

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 2の部分の要件が正直あいまいな印象です。「見出し語」や「基本形の文字列」は日本語の文法では出てこないものです。形態素解析で抽出できる品詞（動詞や名詞）もしくは構文解析を用いた主語や述語などの表現を表していますか？それとも独自の計算解析方法を用いますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
形態素解析や構文解析が難しく、人工無能を自分なりに調べたのですが、オープンソースなどそのまま引用して使えるものがないかと探しておりますが、ご存知でしょうか。ただ、こちらが設定した短いキーワードに反応してユーザーに回答してほしいという機能をつけたいので、形態素解析や構文解析の領域に踏み込まないと難しいでしょうか。ユーザーの文章に反応するキーワードやこちらが予め作成済みの文章の量は多くないので、下記のようなJavaScriptを使った検索機能の応用でできないかなと考えております。もしこの部分についてご存知でしたら何かコメントいただけたらありがたいです。
https://techacademy.jp/magazine/37752
https://www.tam-tam.co.jp/tipsnote/javascript/post11315.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下のようなシンプルな仕組みでなんとかすることを検討してみてはいかがですか。

```
<?php
$user_input = "うまいといえばラーメン"; //ユーザーが入力した文章

//左が反応するキーワード。右が返す文章。
$word = [
    "好き" => "スイーツが好き",
    "嫌い" => "辛いものが嫌い",
    "うまい" => "芋けんぴうまい",
    "まずい" => "カエルのスープまずい",
];

//ユーザー入力にキーワードが含まれているか順に確認
foreach ($word as $keyword => $answer) {
    if (strpos($user_input, $keyword) !== false) {
        echo $answer;
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: 大変遅くなり申し訳ないです。ご回答ありがとうございました。大変参考になったので、その方向で作ってみたいと思います。ありがとうございました。